# Prove that A is a continuous linear operator mapping $C_2[0, 1]$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $C_2[0, 1]$ be the space of all continuous functions equipped with the norm
$$||f||_{L^2[0,1]} =(\int^1_0 f^2(x) dx)^{1/2}.$$
Let $K(x, y)$ be a fixed function of two variables, continuous on the square $[0, 1] × [0, 1]$, and let $A$ be the operator defined by $$Af(x) = \int^ 1_0 K(x, y)f(y) dy.$$
Prove that A is a continuous linear operator mapping $C_2[0, 1]$ into itself.

Proof idea:
first as a reminder:

- $C_2[0, 1]$ is the space of continuous functions on C[0, 1] equipped with $L^2$ norm.
- $L^2[0,1]= \{ f:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbf {C}: \int^1_0 |f(x)|^2 dx<\infty \} $

Linearity $A(\alpha f +\beta g)(x)=\int^ 1_0 K(x, y)(\alpha f +\beta g)(y) dy = \alpha \int^ 1_0 K(x, y)f(y)dy +\beta \int^ 1_0 K(x, y)g(y)dy=\alpha Af(x)+\beta Ag(x)$. by linearity of the integrals.

Boundedness: $K\leq M$ is bounded by some $M$ finite since it is continuous on a closed set. Therefore, $$|Af(x)| = |\int^ 1_0 K(x, y)f(y) dy|\leq M |\int^ 1_0 f(y) dy \leq M ||f||_{L^2[0,1]} \int^ 1_0 dy=M||f||_{L^2[0,1]}<\infty$$

So $A$ is linear and continuous on $C_2[0,1]$.

I am not sure this is complete. Also, do I need also to find $||A||$? Also what is the implication of having $C_2[0,1]$, where do I use this?

Thanks and Regards,

Comment: Yes, $A:C_2[0,1]\rightarrow C_2[0,1]$ is well defined. WTS $Af_1\neq Af_2\Rightarrow f_1\neq f_2$. So $Af_1\neq Af_2\Rightarrow \int_0^1 f_1(y)dy\neq \int_0^1 f_2(y)dy\Rightarrow f_1\neq f_2$.

Comment: Use FTC to show.

Comment: Good point. I know it is continuous and returns a differentiable function by its definition and by FTC. Since the function $f$ (from the domain) is twice differentiable, by integrating it (according to A's definition) A returns a function in x that is in $C_2$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof for continuity is not quite right. To show $A: \mathcal{C}_{2}([0, 1]) \to \mathcal{C}_{2}([0, 1])$ is continuous, let $f \in \mathcal{C}_{2}([0, 1])$. Then:

$$||Af||_{L^{2}([0, 1])}^{2} = ||\int_{0}^{1}K(x, y)f(y)dy||_{L^{2}([0, 1])}^{2} = \int_{0}^{1}|\int_{0}^{1}K(x, y)f(y)dy|^{2}dx  $$
$$\leq \int_{0}^{1}[(\int_{0}^{1}|K(x, y)|^{2}dy)(\int_{0}^{1}|f(y)|^{2}dy)]dx\text{, by Cauchy-Schwarz} $$
$$ = (\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}|K(x, y)|^{2}dx dy)(\int_{0}^{1}|f(y)|^{2}dy) = ||K||_{L^{2}([0, 1]^{2})}^{2}||f||_{L^{2}([0, 1])}^{2} $$

$$\Rightarrow ||Af||_{L^{2}([0, 1]^{2})} \leq ||K||_{L^{2}([0, 1]^{2})}||f||_{L^{2}([0, 1])}$$

Note $||K||_{L^{2}([0, 1]^{2})}^{2} = \int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}|K(x, y)|^{2}dx dy \leq \text{sup}_{(x, y) \in [0, 1]^{2}}|K(x, y)|^{2} = ||K||_{\mathcal{C}_{0}([0, 1]^{2})}^{2} < \infty$, the last inequality from our assumption that $K$ is continuous. This shows that $A$ is a bounded operator, which implies it is continuous.

To find a bound for $||A||$, simply note that from the above, $||A|| \leq ||K||_{L^{2}([0, 1]^{2})}$.

Comment: why $||Af||^2$ and not $||Af||$?

Comment: Recall that $||f||_{L^{2}(X)} = (\int_{X}|f(x)|^{2}d\mu)^{1/2}$. $||f||_{L^{2}(X)}^{2} = \int_{X}|f(x)|^{2}d\mu$ is easier to work with in calculation.

Comment: Yes, I forgot about the definition of $||f||$ in the hypothesis is $(...)^{1/2}$. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Take some poorly behaving function like $K(x,t) := |x-0.5|t$, where $x,t\in [0,1]$ (continuity follows from continuity of multiplication in $\mathbb R$, for example). Take $f(x)\equiv 1$, so it's in $C_2$. Then
$$ Af(x) =\int _0^1K(x,t)f(t)dt = \frac{1}{2}\left\lvert x-\frac{1}{2} \right\rvert,\quad x\in [0,1] $$
is not differentiable (let alone twice differentiable).

You need to assume more of  $K$, I think OR By $C_2[0,1]$ you mean $C_0[0,1]$ equipped with the $L_2$ norm.

Comment: I don't think OP is saying $\mathcal{C}_{2}([0, 1])$ is the space of twice continuously differentiable functions on $[0, 1]$, but rather, is $\mathcal{C}_{0}([0, 1])$ (space of continuous functions on $[0, 1]$) equipped with the $L^{2}$ norm.

Comment: fixed a typo, $f\in C_2$ not $L_2$

Comment: I see. This answers my questions on the role of $C_2[0,1]$. Now it makes sense.